# Communicate Between Android Phone and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android

I was planning on connecting my Raspberry Pi to my Android phone to both tether internet and open a TCP/IP port to communicate between an Android app and RasPi program, but it seems the Android SDK is only compiled for i386. Does anyone have any alternative options to do something similar?

As a side note, it seems there is an ADB-library written for micros: http://code.google.com/p/microbridge/. Perhaps something similar could be done on the RasPi?

Comment: I don't understand the 'connecting' part of your question, you are talking about physically connecting using a (USB) cable? If so, why? A network connection to communicate between the Android and some program running on the RPi is enough to get what you want (client / server comm) ? Why do you want to use the ADB, what is it's role in this setup?

Comment: @ikku Not sure what the OP was specifically thinking, but the problem with the solution you describe is this: connecting the pi to a phone via a network would  require the phone to be connected to a wireless network. However, Android phones will not connect to the internet via their phone network if there is an active wireless connection - they always assume that a wireless connection has a better connection to the internet than their own.  Doing this therefore prevents the tethering to the internet that OP was asking for.  ADB has an "adb ppp" command to open a PPP connection over USB, ...

Comment: ... which would solve this solution, if there was an available adb implementation, which is I guess why the OP mentioned that.